# The value of Euler function of $\phi(p^k)$ when $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Prove that the value of Euler function of $\phi(p^k)$ when $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer is,

$$\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$$

I saw similar posts for the same questions, but I am still confused about the following.

**Question**: the divisors of $p^k$ are,

$$1, p, p^2, p^3, \cdots, p^k$$

Those divisors should not be relatively prime to $p^k$ as the $gcd(p^k, divisor_i) \ne 1$. We can see that we have $p^k$ such divisors that are not relatively prime to $p^k$ as I understand it.

Also, we have multiples of $p$ up to $p^k$ cannot be relatively prime to $p^k$ for the same reason as $gcd(p^k, multipleP_i) \ne 1$,

$$p, 2p, 3p, \cdots, p^{k-1}p$$

Clearly we have $p^{k-1}$ of such multiples, so we should have the total number of numbers that are not relatively prime to $p^k$ as (based on how I understand it),

$$\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$$

**Question**: How do we know that those only multiples of $p$ and divisors of $p^k$ are the only possibilities of the numbers not to be relatively prime to $p^k$? How do we know that there are not other numbers in between that could also be not relatively prime to $p^k$?

Comment: The only way you can fail to be relatively prime to $p^k$ is to have $p$ as a factor.  There are only $p^{k-1}$ such integers, as your argument shows.

Comment: @Randall. Thank you. Could you please explain how do you know this for certain? Why it's not possible for $p+q$, $p/q$ or $p\times q$ to not be relatively prime as well? Why divisors of $p^k$ are not considered as relatively prime above in the question? As the true answer is $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$?

Comment: It helps to write out an example.  $2^3=8$ and the integers from 1 to 8 that share a common with 8 are 2, 4, 6, and 8.  They are all multiples of $2$.

Comment: A divisor of $p^k$ (besides 1) certainly canNOT be relatively prime, since such a divisor has the form $p^j$, and note that $p$ is now a common factor.

Comment: @Randall. Thank you. So $\phi(n)=p^k-(p^{k-1}+divisors)$ and not $\phi(n)=p^k-p^{k-1}$? Please, why the divisors were not counted in the final answer and only multiples of $p$ were counted to find $\phi(p^k)$?

Comment: I don't understand.  Note in my example that 4, a divisor of 8, was indeed discounted.  The divisors are correctly removed when you compute the $p^{k-1}$ members that fail to be relatively prime.

Comment: I see your confusion:  don't you see that a divisor $p^j$ is indeed included in the list $p, 2p, 3p, \ldots,... p^{k-1}p$?  It will occur at the $p^{j-1}$st position, giving $p^{j-1}p=p^j$. This was my point above.

Comment: @Randall. Thank you. So $p^2$ occurs at $p^{j-(j-1)}p$ and so on. We thus removed all multipliers of $p$ as well as divisors of $p$. The total number is $p^k$ and we subtract those multipliers and divisors which are in total $p^{k-1}$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, roughly, though it's simpler to see that $p^2$ occurs as $p \cdot p$.

Comment: I see you accepted my A almost as soon as I posted it, which is dangerous because I usually need at least 10 minutes to fix all my killer typos. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is prime and $x,k\in \Bbb N.$

(1). If $\gcd(x,p^n)>1$ then for some prime $q$ we have $q\,|\,\gcd(x,p^n)\,|\,p^k,$ so $q|p^k.$ But the only prime divisor of $p^k$ is $p,$ by the uniqueness of prime decomposition, so $q=p,$ so $p=q\,|\,\gcd(x,p^n)\,|\,x,$ so $p|x,$ so $$\exists y\in \Bbb N\,(x=py).$$

(2).  If $\gcd(x,p^n)=1$ then $p\not |\,x\;$ ( otherwise $p>1$ is a common divisor of $x$ and of $p^k$) so $$\neg \exists y\in \Bbb N\,(x=py). $$

Therefore $$\{x\in \Bbb N: x\le p^k\land \gcd (x,p)>1\}=\{x\in \Bbb N: x\le p^k\land p|x\}=$$ $$=\{py: y\in \Bbb N\land py\le p^k\}.$$ This last set (above) has the same number of members as $\{y\in\Bbb N: y\le p^{k-1}\}$ does, which is $p^{k-1}$ members. Therefore $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}.$

Comment: Unique explanation. Thank you. But I am not sure about how  $\{py: y\in \Bbb N\land py\le p^k\}$ has indeed $p^{k-1}$ elements?

Comment: Let $A=\{y\in\Bbb N: y\le p^{k-1}\}$ and $B=\{py\in\Bbb N:y\in \Bbb N\land py\le p^k\}.$ For $y\in A$ let $f(y)=py.$ Then $f:A\to B$ is a bijection.